# How can I filter posts when the meta_value is a serialize object?

Tags: post-meta

I'm doing a dropdown in my post custom type just to filter the content when is completed or not.

my meta_value is a serialize object like `"a:3:{s:5:"email";s:21:"mrsxcvsfesr@gmail.com";s:9:"store";s:6:"testes";s:5:"token";s:34:"$P$B7efpLZUWWyB4QkhG0YaYyIwXRAj.3.";}"`
and my job is to check if the token is null or not

[image]

**CustomPostTypeController.php**

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts',[ $this, 'dropdown_status_filter']);
add_filter( 'parse_query', [ $this, 'filter_request_query'])


public function dropdown_status_filter($post_type){

    if('ctp_dasboard' !== $post_type) {
      return; //filter your post
    }

    $selected = '';
    $request_attr = 'status_filter';

    if ( isset($_REQUEST[$request_attr]) ) {
      $selected = $_REQUEST[$request_attr];
    }

    echo '<select id="status_filter-loc" name="status_filter">';
      echo ($selected === '1') ? "'<option value='1' selected>Done</option>'" : "'<option value='1'>Done</option>'";
      echo ($selected === '2') ? "'<option value='2' selected>Pending</option>'" : "'<option value='2'>Pending</option>'";
    echo '</select>';
  }

public function filter_request_query($query){
    //modify the query only if it admin and main query.
    if( !(is_admin() AND $query->is_main_query()) ){ 
      return $query;
    }

    //we want to modify the query for the targeted custom post and filter option
    if( !('ctp_dasboard' === $query->query['post_type'] AND isset($_REQUEST['status_filter']) ) ){
      return $query;
    }

    //for the default value of our filter no modification is required   
    if(0 == $_REQUEST['status_filter']){
      return $query;
    }

    //modify the query_vars.


    // $value = "";
    // var_dump($_REQUEST['status_filter'] === '1');

    if ( $_REQUEST['status_filter'] === '1'){
        // global $wpdb;
        // $meta_key = 'form_ctp';
        // $meta_value = '"token";N;';
        // $mid = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value LIKE %s ", $meta_key, $meta_value) );
        // dd($mid);

        // // The Query
        $args = [
            'post_type'    => 'ctp_dasboard',
            ['meta_query' => [
                'key'     => 'form_ctp', 
                'value'   => 'token";N;', // this is when token is null
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ]]
        ];

        // dd($args);
        $query = new \WP_Query( $args );    

        // dd($the_query);


    }
    if ( $_REQUEST['status_filter'] === '2'){

    }

    return $query;
  }
```

Comment: The solution is the same as [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/336718/147428)

Comment: That solution will check for the token key being set, but not if the token value is null. I think you may be able to modify it to look for `s:5:"token";N;` which is a null value or `s:5:"token";s:0:"";` for an empty string.

Comment: I think that if you intend to filter posts by `token` property / attribute, you should store it in a separate meta field instead of as an array.