# Filtering posts by ACF meta query

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

I am trying to filter posts by a **meta_query**, based on a post field. 
The field type is **checkbox**.

The field configuration is:

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array (
    'key' => 'group_5a579h8fs9a98a',
    'title' => 'Bingo Options',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'layout' => 'vertical',
            'choices' => array (
                'bingo' => 'This is Bingo promotion',
            ),
            'default_value' => array (
            ),
            'allow_custom' => 0,
            'save_custom' => 0,
            'toggle' => 0,
            'return_format' => 'value',
            'key' => 'field_59jafj0s5c9ea',
            'name' => 'is_bingo_promotion',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'instructions' => 'Select this if you want this promotion to be shown on bingo page',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array (
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'promotions',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => 1,
    'description' => '',
));
```

So, inside the WP I get a checkbox. and when it is checked, i want this query to get it for me:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'promotions',
    'posts_per_page' =>-1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'is_bingo_promotion',
            'value' => 'bingo',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

WP_Query( $args );
```

But this query doesn't filter the posts. It gets all of them. 
What am i doing wrong with the meta_query?

P.S.
I know that the field type should have been true_false instead, but this is due to legacy.

Comment: If you're storing a post meta value purely to group or toggle posts, a taxonomy/terms could be 100x faster, just tell ACF to use the taxonomy to store the data instead of post meta. You'll even get free post archives, URLs, templates, etc as a result, and your queries will be easier, and significantly faster

Comment: Look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/336715/meta-query-in-doesnt-work-with-acf-checkbox-filter)

Comment: Thank you both.

@TomJNowell i changed the field to taxonomy like you suggested. 
From what i see, this is the right way to do what i wanted.